# Is local minimum/maximum necessarily global when it's the only stationary point of a continuous & differentiable function?

Tags: functions, optimization, maxima-minima, stationary-point

Couldn't find this theorem even though it feels very intuitive to me.

If the $f:R^n  \to R$ is continuous, and has only one stationary point - a local minimum/maximuma. Doesn't it necessarily makes it global?

If not - can you please give an example?

If yes - where is it proven?

Comment: $f$ needs to be not only continuous but differentiable, no?

Comment: @leonbloy yeah, thank you

Comment: For $n=1$: you need $f \in C^1$ (the function is not only continuos but continuosly differentiable). (a counterxample:  $f(x) = e^x - |x + 1|$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n=1$: you need $f \in C^1$ (the function is not only continuous but continuously differentiable). (a counterxample:  $f(x) = e^x - |x + 1|$)

For $n>1$ things are more complicated. See [here](https://www.math.tamu.edu/%7Etom.vogel/gallery/node16.html)

Comment: If it is continuously differentiable for n=1 how do you prove that if there is one stationary point then it must be absolute max/min

Comment: If $x_0$ it's a local minimum, the derivative  is positive on the right - in a neighbourhood, and hence it's positive for all $x>x_0$, (Bolzano theorem) hence $f$ is increasing, hence $f(x) > f(x_0)$ $\forall x > x_0$ . The same goes for the other side. Hence it's a global minimum.

Comment: Ok your proof assumes that the function is continuously differentiable what if there was only *one critical point* how would you prove it then this is also true as said in link (this is more general)